# Advanced search code does not bring relevant results (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have written this CodeIgniter code for an advanced search. this advanced search has only a list of provinced for the uses to select from. But, I have problem, when searching, it brings results from other cities not selected by the user. Here is the code to match for the term:

```
$db->or_like("title", $_POST['search-term']); // OR 
$db->or_like("content", $_POST['search-term']);   // OR 
$db->or_like("name", $_POST['search-term']);    // OR   
$db->or_like("keywords", $_POST['search-term']);    // OR
```

And here is part of code responsible for matching with the selected province:

```
if(isset($_POST['province']) && $_POST['province'] != "0")
        { 
            $db->where("province", $_POST['province']); 
            if(isset($_POST['cities']) && $_POST['cities'] != "0")
            {
            $db->where("city", $_POST['cities']);   
            }
        } // AND
```

And here is the code responsible for getting the data into an array:

```
$search_result = $db->get("ads")->result_array();
```

It is also worth mentioning that when I change the `or_like` to `like` it yields no result.

Here is the generated QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM (`ads`) WHERE `status` = 2 AND `province` = '5' AND `title` LIKE '%شریف%' OR `content` LIKE '%شریف%' OR `name` LIKE '%شریف%' OR `keywords` LIKE '%شریف%' ORDER BY `stars` DESC
```

It seems to be sound and OK, but the results are not...

Comment: show the generated query, that would be just easier

Comment: I use the standalone CI class outside the CI and i don't know how to print the query with this class

Comment: `echo $this->db->last_query();`

Comment: i have added the printed query

Comment: so what are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: I expect to get the item which is only with province "5", while it shows result with other province values such as "8"

Answer (score 1):

try this query then,

```
SELECT * FROM (`ads`) WHERE `status` = 2 AND `province` = '5' AND(
 `title` LIKE '%شریف%'
 OR `content` LIKE '%شریف%' OR `name` LIKE '%شریف%' OR `keywords` LIKE '%شریف%') 
ORDER BY `stars` DESC
```

**Update:**
in CI you can try it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (`ads`) WHERE `status` = 2 AND `province` = '5' AND(
     `title` LIKE '%شریف%'
     OR `content` LIKE '%شریف%' OR `name` LIKE '%شریف%' OR `keywords` LIKE '%شریف%') 
    ORDER BY `stars` DESC";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

this would solve your problem.

**Side Notes:**
your code is saying welcome to SQL injection. 
be aware of what you are doing.

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter and don't know how to implement what you have suggested

Comment: owo...that would make it very hard to change the code..CI should have some solution for it in active record technique