# CodeIgniter generated Statement does not give results as expected

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, search

I have printed out a CI generated code, so to talk about the statement, since it would be easier. Here it is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`ads`) 
WHERE `status` = 2 AND `province` = '5' AND `title` LIKE '%شریف%' 
      OR `content` LIKE '%شریف%' OR `name` LIKE '%شریف%' 
      OR `keywords` LIKE '%شریف%' 
ORDER BY `stars` DESC
```

But, it shows results which are with value "8" for the province, while it is said in statement to only get results with province "5". Why it does not work correctly?

Comment: do not re-post the same question every 10 seconds.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310569/advanced-search-code-does-not-bring-relevant-results-codeigniter/20310874#20310874

Answer (score 1):

The operator `and` has a higher precedence than the operator `or`.  That means that if you query:

```
select  *
from    applicants
where   expected_salary < 10
        or knowledge = 'high' 
        and has_residency_permit = 'true'
```

you could get someone with a low salary without a residency permit.  The solution is to use parenthesis to override precedence:

```
select  *
from    applicants
where   (expected_salary < 10
        or knowledge = 'high')
        and has_residency_permit = 'true'
```

This query will only return applicants with a residency permit.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this (`CI` supports [Custom string](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select))

```
$where = "title LIKE '%شریف%' OR content LIKE '%شریف%' OR name LIKE '%شریف%' OR keywords LIKE '%شریف%'";
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('ads');
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->where("status = 2 AND province = '5'");
$this->db->order_by('stars', 'desc');
```

Go to the given link above and look for `custom string`.